# Dificuldade com web scraping

Tags: python

```html
<tr bgcolor="FFF8DC">
    <td valign="top">25/06/2014 20:37</td>
    <td valign="top">25/06/2014</td>
    <td>
        <a href="Javascript:AbreArquivo('430489');">BROOKFIELD INCORPORAÇÕES S.A.</a>
        <br>
        Disponibilização do Laudo de Avaliação da pretendida oferta pública para a aquisição das
        ações de emissão da Companhia em circulação no mercado
    </td>
</tr>
```

Utilizando a biblioteca BeautifulSoup eu consigo ler a seguinte página:

http://siteempresas.bovespa.com.br/consbov/ExibeFatosRelevantesCvm.asp?site=C

Estou com dificuldade para ler via python o número de protocolo do html acima '430489'. Este número será utilizado para baixar um pdf. Pretendo criar uma função que terá como argumento este número e que automaticamente baixará o pdf no meu mac.

Comment: Rodrigues, é uma pergunta antiga mas, alguma das respostas resolveu o problema?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer isso de diversas maneiras, como mencionado pelo [mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/215/mgibsonbr),
para extrair um *pedaço* de uma string o uso de [**expressões regulares**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=regex#re.RegexObject) é comumente utilizado para esse fim, tal como [**manipular a string**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

Assumindo que tenhamos a variável `conteudo` que armazena o *html* tenha as seguintes informações:

```
conteudo = '''
<tr bgcolor="FFF8DC">
    <td valign="top">25/06/2014 20:37</td>
    <td valign="top">25/06/2014</td>
    <td>
        <a href="Javascript:AbreArquivo('430489');">BROOKFIELD INCORPORAÇÕES S.A.</a>
        <br>
        Disponibilização do Laudo de Avaliação da pretendida oferta pública para a aquisição das
        ações de emissão da Companhia em circulação no mercado
    </td>
</tr>
'''
```

### Manipulação da string

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def getProtocol(html):
   soup = BeautifulSoup(conteudo)
   href = unicode(soup.a['href'].partition('AbreArquivo')[2])

   numero = [int(i) for i in href if i.isnumeric()]
   return int(numero)

protocolo = getProtocol(conteudo)
# Fazer a requisição do PDF aqui
```

Acima utilizamos o método [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) para dividir a *string* na primeira ocorrência do separador(no caso é `AbreArquivo`).

A *string* a qual queremos dividir vem do seguinte modo: `Javascript:AbreArquivo('430489');`. Ao usar `partition('AbreArquivo')[2]` teremos como resultado: `('430489');`

É criado uma lista chamada `numero` que conterá apenas números, percorremos caractere por caractere e verificamos se é um número, se for, é adicionado na lista.

### Expressões Regulares

Para extrair um número você pode usar a expressão `\d+` ou `[0-9]+` para capturar um ou mais números.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

def getProtocol(html):
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
   href = soup.a['href']

   numero = re.findall(r'\d+', href)[0]
   return int(numero)

protocolo = getProtocol(conteudo)
# Fazer a requisição do PDF aqui
```

Vale ressaltar que, se o conteúdo a tratar vier num formato diferente você provavelmente terá que adaptar o modo de tratar a string ou a expressão.

Answer (score 2):

Estou assumindo que você já conseguiu uma referência para o elemento `<a>` desejado, e consegue também extrair o conteúdo do atributo `href` (se estou enganado nessas suposições, acrescente mais detalhes na pergunta). O problema então se resume a extrair o número `430489` da string `Javascript:AbreArquivo('430489');`, certo?

Não existe solução generalizada para isso, uma vez que o `href` suportaria a princípio qualquer JavaScript válido. Entretanto, se você **sabe** que seu HTML virá sempre nesse formato, basta usar uma simples função de substring para extrair a parte desejada:

```python
href = soup.tr.a['href']
arq_str = href[len("Javascript:AbreArquivo('") : -len("');")]
arq_int = int(arq_str)
```

Caso não esteja familiarizado com a operação de substring (sublista), `x[inicio:fim]` cria uma nova string/lista iniciando na posição `inicio` e terminando logo antes da posição `fim`. Se `fim` for negativo, ele começa a contar do final da string (i.e. `len(x) - fim`).

Fazendo `inicio = len(prefixo)` e `fim = -len(sufixo)` garante-se que somente o "meio" será selecionado, sem depender de "números mágicos". Aí é só converter para número, se aplicável.

Answer (score 0):

**Somente Beautifulsoup**

```
from bs4 import Beautifulsoup

conteudo = '''
<tr bgcolor="FFF8DC">
    <td valign="top">25/06/2014 20:37</td>
    <td valign="top">25/06/2014</td>
    <td>
        <a href="Javascript:AbreArquivo('430489');">BROOKFIELD INCORPORAÇÕES S.A.</a>
        <br>
        Disponibilização do Laudo de Avaliação da pretendida oferta pública para a aquisição das
        ações de emissão da Companhia em circulação no mercado
    </td>
</tr>
'''
soup = Beautifulsoup(conteudo, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select('a[href*="AbreArquivo"]')[0]['href'].split("'")[1])

#430489
```